# Varimp() from party package produces different results with each run

Tags: r, random-forest, party

I am using the party package to create a random forest model using the cforest() function. However, when I try to look at the variable importance values of my model using the varimp function, the varimp function produces different values for my features. Is there any way of fixing this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack OVerflow. Please consult the documentation on how to as a good question: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 

It would benefit you to provide a minimum reproducible example (some code) and data to go with it.

Answer (score 1):

For any process using random values - such as creating a random forest model, or finding the variable importance using random permutation - slight variations from each run is to be expected.

If you want to "lock in" one of these values, e.g. to make your analysis reproducable, you can use `set.seed(<any number>)`. Under is an example:

```r
library(party)

# Create model
mod <- cforest(hp ~ ., mtcars)

# Without seed we get different values each time

varimp(mod)[1]

#>      mpg 
#> 498.8208


varimp(mod)[1]

#>      mpg 
#> 513.8174


# However, if we set the seed, we get the same result each time

set.seed(1)

varimp(mod)[1]

#>     mpg 
#> 464.639

set.seed(1)

varimp(mod)[1]

#>     mpg 
#> 464.639
```

---

#### Update

Note that `set.seed()` still gives different values with repeated calls to random functions, but in a predictable way. For example, if I call `rnorm(1)` twice, I get two different values. But with the same seed, I get the same two values each time I reset the seed.

```r
set.seed(1)
rnorm(1)
#> [1] -0.6264538
rnorm(1)
#> [1] 0.1836433

set.seed(1)
rnorm(1)
#> [1] -0.6264538
rnorm(1)
#> [1] 0.1836433
```

You can reset the seed by calling `set.seed()` multiple times in your script, or by restarting your R session before you run your script (shortcut keys are `CTRL + SHIFT + F10` for Windows).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am already using set.seed(1), right above the line that creates my model, for reproducibility. Shouldn't this prevent variability in the results from running varimp() after? Or do I have to set the seed again before each call to varimp()?

Comment: `set.seed` will give you new values each time you call a random function, but in a predictable way. For example, if I call `set.seed(1); rnorm(1); rnorm(1)` I don't get the same number twice. However, I do get -0.63 and 0.18, and if I call `set.seed(1)` again I will get -0.63 and 0.18 again. The same applies if you restart your R session. I've updated my answer to reflect this.